# How to resample a raster layer to match a specific raster layer's cell size?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, resampling

I would like to resample the cell size of a GeoTIFF raster layer with dimensions equal to the reference file (a Sentinel-2 B12 band with 20 m resolution to 10 m resolution).
I use the following code but doesn't work because the new raster created remains the same with 20 m resolution of cell size. Can someone help me with this?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) to achieve this.

```py
from osgeo import gdal


# open reference file and get resolution
referenceFile = "Path to reference file"
reference = gdal.Open(referenceFile, 0)  # this opens the file in only reading mode
referenceTrans = reference.GetGeoTransform()
x_res = referenceTrans[1]
y_res = -referenceTrans[5]  # make sure this value is positive

# specify input and output filenames
inputFile = "Path to input file"
outputFile = "Path to output file"

# call gdal Warp
kwargs = {"format": "GTiff", "xRes": x_res, "yRes": y_res}
ds = gdal.Warp(outputFile, inputFile, **kwargs)
```

Note that `gdal.Warp()` is just a Python wrapper for `gdalwarp` (which is a command line utility) so you can pass the same arguments you would pass to a `gdalwarp` call. The only thing to keep in mind is that the argument names might be a little bit different but you can check the equivalent names in the [documentation](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#WarpOptions). You can control other things such as the source and target spatial reference as well as the resampling algorithm used.

Comment: +1 But just being picky, `gdal.Warp` isn't a Python wrapper for `gdalwarp`.  You can still run `gdal.Warp` if you remove the commandline utilities.  All the code got pulled out of the commandline utilities into GDAL core libraries as of v2.1 (https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc59.1_utilities_as_a_library.html).

Comment: @user2856 Thank you for the information. I thought all these functions were just wrappers for the command line utilities.

Comment: Think of it as `gdal.Warp` and `gdalwarp` are python and cmd line wrappers for the C++ `GDALWarp` library function.

Comment: How I can define the 'inputTrans'? Says that is not defined.

Comment: You don't need to define `inputTrans` nor any other information about the input file. You just need to specify its name and `gdal.Warp` will take care of the rest.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c91b2b97bd0b> in <module>
      3 reference = gdal.Open(referenceFile, 0)  # this opens the file in only reading mode
      4 referenceTrans = reference.GetGeoTransform
----> 5 x_res = inputTrans[1]
      6 y_res = -inputTrans[5]  # make sure this value is positive

NameError: name 'inputTrans' is not defined

Comment: This is the error that I get.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I confused the variable names. I just edited the code in my answer.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3263b3f04fb3> in <module>
      3 reference = gdal.Open(referenceFile, 0)  # this opens the file in only reading mode
      4 referenceTrans = reference.GetGeoTransform
----> 5 x_res = referenceTrans[1]
      6 y_res = -referenceTrans[5]  # make sure this value is positive

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Now occures an other error in line 6. 'method' object is not subscriptable. I don't understand why. The brackets?

Comment: Yeah, should have been `reference.GetGeoTransform()`. Hope it works now!

Comment: It doesn't work. I got the same resolution... I'll try to investigate. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104573/discussion-between-marcelo-villa-and-danielkovacs).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, I solved that using the simple export feature of QGIS. There, in the export menus you can :

1. Define the extent (keeping the same as the reference layer),
2. Match the dimension/resolution of the image, i.e. number of row x column (instead if you want, you can also provide the resolution same as the reference layer)
3. In the projection tab, you can select the same projection as the reference layer (either select it manually or select the reference layer of metadata copying

So, in this way you can match the metadata of the image with any reference image. Doing this would save you time.

EXAMPLE

---

In this below example I am taking two datasets,

1. E_LC09_033035_20220522 (reference dataset)
2. 20220519_VV_abs_ortho_Clipped_rep (whose metadata to change)

First, Check the extent, size, resolution, and projection of reference data that we want to impose on the second image, here for example our reference image has EPSG 3857, 10 m pixel spacing, and an extent slightly different than the other.

The images below reproduce the same procedure.

[image: Properties of 1st image (reference image)]
[image: Properties of 2nd image]
[image: method to export]
[image: option to change extent and projection]
[image: option to change resolution]

When you have changed all of these properties accordingly, then save the image providing the path and name.